# Find the particular set of users and remove from Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I want to create Azure logic app, which runs after every minute. That should look for all the users in a subscription which user id(user name) doesn't ends with "myorg.com", if it find any the user with userid doesn't end with "myorg.com" then delete that user.

I tried looking in the web but i could not found any action which is similar to above. What will be the connector i should use to accomplish above requirement? or let me know if there is any other approach to do this? Could any one please help me on this.

Edit: I want to delete the user from from Subscription.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this every minute, I believe you want to validate for users that are added to the subscription. If that's the case, I would suggest you to use Event Grid and the Azure Subscription publisher, which can publish an event every time a user is added to the Azure Subscription, then push that event to the Logic App, and let the Logic App check whether the user id has the expected domain and send the corresponding alerts.

Event Grid will allow you to react to events instead of having to poll every minute.

You can find a demo of a very similar scenario here:

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Event-Grid

HTH

Comment: Really very very thanks for the answer. I am searching for this answer for lot of time. I did the same which is explained in the video but Azure event grid trigger is not getting fired. I am not the administrator for the Tenant. Is that the reason event is not getting fired?

Comment: Update the above comment. I have free 30 days account. I created a tenant and created a free subscription under a new tenant. I did the same as explained in the video. But my logic app event is not getting triggered at all. I saw the the run history  of logic app and there is no log created. Is it due to i am using free subscription?

Comment: Hi Paco de la Cruz, I  have edited my question could you  help me on this please.